# sql - Select Statement where not exists a condition for each id ?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table in my Database and i hava a history with entrys:

Tabelname: Activity

```
ActivityID | DateBegin  | DateEnd 
1            2013-01-01   2013-01-15
1            2013-01-15   9999-12-31
2            2013-01-20   2013-03-15
```

Now i want to write a Query which will return the id with the DateEnd = 
9999-12-31. In this example i want the return only id 2

I wrote this query, but it doesn't function: (I get a return statement of NULL)

```
SELECT ActivityID 
  FROM [dbo].[Activity]
  where NOT EXISTS  (SELECT ActivityID from
                  Activity where DateEnd ='9999-12-31')
```

Can somebody help me ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why do you use the `NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: jus use `select * from table where dateend <> '9999-12-31'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ActivityID 
FROM   dbo.Activity As x
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT ActivityID
         FROM   dbo.Activity
         WHERE  DateEnd ='9999-12-31'
         AND    ActivityID = x.ActivityID
       )
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return all the IDs that don't have any row with date 9999-12-31, you should first check which IDs you don't want to be returned, then avoid them in your query.

So the query becomes:

```
SELECT ActivityID 
    FROM [dbo].[Activity]
    WHERE ActivityID NOT IN (SELECT ActivityID from
              [dbo].[Activity] WHERE DateEnd ='9999-12-31')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it

```
 SELECT ActivityId  from Activity  where  DateEnd != CONVERT(varchar(10), '9999-12-31',101)
```

Comment: check output of your query